# Present continuous tense with the time element "everyday"

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatical to use the present continuous when "everyday" is the time element involved, as in "I'm studying English everyday."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although it is more correct to separate the two words "every day." At least in standard US usage, "everyday" is an adjective:

> She carried her ***everyday*** umbrella.  She had a special one that she only used on Sundays.

For a ***daily*** action, we'd use "every day" as an adverb phrase.

> I'm working hard in school.  I am studying English ***every day***.

Although there is no absolute reason to avoid the present progressive, many would prefer to omit -ing ending and say

> I ***study*** English every day.

Please note that this is a *descriptive* answer, not a *prescriptive* one.  Prescriptivists may raise their hackles as they will.